# How to use istringstream to determine if first number in text file via file redirection on terminal in mac is a valid integer for the program?

Tags: c++, macos

I have random text files that I have to read and check if the first number of the file is a positive integer. If not, the program terminates. Hoping to get some help figuring out why my isValid method isn't working, and how to properly redirect my input file on terminal to the code (right now I just

```
bool isValid(int& number)
{
   string integer;
   getline(cin,integer);
   if (istringstream(integer)>>number )
   {
      if(number>0)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         cout<<"Bad Data. Need (+)"<<endl;
         return false;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout<<"Bad Data. Int needed";
      return false;
   }
}
```

I defined a method to call in main :

I call this in main by declaring an int representing the number and calling the function on it.

```
int numberInput;
isValid(numberInput);
```

Ideally I want to be able to just drag my executable to terminal and then direct the text file into terminal to read the first line and validate the program. Am I screwing up by how I am calling it in main? Or is it my attempt at entering inputfile in terminal by dragging the executable path onto terminal then "<" then the file location?

Comment: Where is `num` defined?

Comment: Also this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119366/how-to-check-if-the-input-number-integer-not-float/40119691#40119691

Comment: In fact possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119366/how-to-check-if-the-input-number-integer-not-float/40119691#40119691

Comment: fixed. I think my problem is honestly using terminal on mac to run the exe, input the file and return the output. According to my TA, my method looks ok it might be how I am either calling it in main or I don't have the redirection correct on terminal.