# Which flag in cin turns to false when you enter a wrong type input

Tags: c++, while-loop, casting, boolean, cin

When i use cin to get an **int** and user enter a **float** number, apparently nothing is wrong; but when you use **cin** in the condition of a while, it terminates while. like this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, sum = 0, n = 0;
    cout << "enter an integer: ";
    
    while(cin >> a){
        sum += a;
        cout << "enter another integer: ";
        n++;
    }
    
    cout << "Total count of integers = " << n << endl;
    cout << "sum = " << sum;        
}
```

there is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119366/how-to-check-if-the-input-number-integer-not-float); but this solution doesnt match my case, because **cin** is not in condition statement. **cin** cast my data and i cant access real input.

I know **cin.fail()** return true when the cin received a wrong type(for example when you expect int and user enters a char). But i want to know what exactly will happen to **cin** when i expected an int and user enters a float number? what flag will turn to false to stop the cin?? and how can i get the exact input without casting?

thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you just run your program, but check the flags after each iteration, so that on failure you'll know? You don't need us for this.

Comment: @einpoklum how can i do this? i am new in programming.

Comment: Read about `std::istream` and its flags, e.g. at [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (cppreference.com). `cin.fail()` may be useful to you in particular.

Comment: No flags get set when you ask for an int but the user enters a float. The beginning of a float is a valid int so there is no error. If this is not what you want then you have to do some extra work. Read all the input as a string, check if the string matches your expectations of an integer and then convert the string to an integer.

Comment: @john there is a flag but i dont know what. if everything is ok, the while shouldn't stop receiving user inputs, but when the user enters a flaot instead of an int, the while stops receiving further inputs.

Comment: The flag is `fail` as you know. If the user enters say `123.456` then the program will read one integer (123) but if you try to read a second integer then that will fail (because `.456` is not a valid integer) and set the fail flag.

Comment: @Saman C++ I/O is pretty simple minded. If you want anything more sophisticated then you have to do the extra work. Start reading **strings** and analyzing the data you have read.

Comment: This is sort of from the wrong perspective. The user doesn't enter an `int` or a `float`. They enter **text**, and the stream extractor tries to **convert** that text to the appropriate type. "123.45" can be converted to `int` by converting the first three characters.